# Sort table based on version number

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sort a table based on version number with the highest at the top. If the cell starts with "v" followed by a digit it's considered a version number. Otherwise it should be sorted at the bottom of the table alphabetically.

The result is currently exactly the way I want it, except for v2.0 should come before v2a, and v2a should come before v2b. I know that my `parseFloat()` is messing that up, but how can I do this in a better way?

```js
function sortTable(table, order, selector, target) {
 selector = selector || 'th:first-child, td:first-child';
 var asc = order === 'asc';
 target = target || '';
 
 var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table;
 var nodes = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
 var sortedNodes = Array.prototype.slice.apply(nodes);
 sortedNodes.sort(function (a, b) {
  var textA = a.querySelector(selector).textContent;
  var textB = b.querySelector(selector).textContent;
  if( target == 'versions' )
  {
   if (textA.match(/^v\d.*/i)) {
    textA = parseFloat(textA.substr(1));
   }
   if (textB.match(/^v\d.*/i)) {
    textB = parseFloat(textB.substr(1));
   }
  
  }
  result = textA - textB;
  if (isNaN(result))
  {
   return (asc && textB.toString() != '' ) ? textA.toString().localeCompare(textB) : textB.toString().localeCompare(textA);
  }
  else
  {
   return (asc) ? -result : result;
  }
 });
 tbody.textContent = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < sortedNodes.length; i++) {
  tbody.appendChild(sortedNodes[i]);
 }
}
sortTable(document.getElementById('versions'), 'asc', '', 'versions');
```

```html
<table id="versions">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v3.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2a</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>No version number</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v1.0 Work in Progress</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Your current code already reads in the order you want: 
v3.0
v2b
v2a
v2.0
v1.0 Work in Progress
No version number
Text

Comment: You want v2a to be *higher version* than v2b? And v2.0 to be *higher version* than v2a? Is that a bit counter-intuitive?

Comment: @chatnoir It is, but that's how I need to sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split out the version number and suffix with a RegEx to ensure the numeric portion is handled correctly.

I'm not 100% sure this snippet covers *every possible case* as written. It handles your sample data and could easily be tuned to handle edge cases if they exist.

<strike>I've omitted the DOM stuff in the interests of sorting clarity and simplicity.</strike> I've updated the snippet to demonstrate basic table sorting in addition to the raw text values.

```js
const values = [
  "Text",
  "v2b",
  "v3.0",
  "v2a",
  "",
  "v2.0",
  "v30.4alpha",
  "No version number",
  "v1.0 Work in Progress",
];

// regex to separate the numeric version from the suffix
// e.g. "v2.0a" => ["2.0", "a"]
const version = /v(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(.*)/;

function getSortValue (item) {
  if (item == null ) {
    return item;
  }
  
  // might want to do something more robust here.
  // if it's not a string this assumes it's a tr
  // and the first cell has the text we care about.
  return typeof item === "string"
    ? item
    : item.firstChild.textContent;
}

function sort(av, bv) {
  const a = getSortValue(av);
  const b = getSortValue(bv);
  
  if (b && !a) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (a && !b) {
    return -1;
  }
  // get the numeric version and suffix for each item,
  // OR'd with [] for cases where the regex doesn't match
  const [, aVersion = 0, aSuffix = ''] = version.exec(a) || [];
  const [, bVersion = 0, bSuffix = ''] = version.exec(b) || [];

  // sort on the numeric portion
  const versionDiff = parseFloat(bVersion) - parseFloat(aVersion);

  // if the numeric versions are the same
  // sort on the suffix
  if (versionDiff === 0) {
    return aSuffix.localeCompare(bSuffix) || a.localeCompare(b);
  }

  // numeric versions are different; sorting them is enough.
  return versionDiff;
}

// sort raw text values
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(values.sort(sort), null, 2);

// sort table rows
const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));
rows.sort(sort);
const tbody = rows[0].parentElement;
rows.forEach(r => tbody.append(r));
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n - 1) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table id="versions">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v3.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2a</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>v2.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>No version number</td></tr>
  <tr><td>v1.0 Work in Progress</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only tweak would be to get "No version number", "Text" and "" at the end. Also, does this work with v20.1a and v20.1b or is it locked to only one digit?

Comment: Works with any number of digits. I'll update the sample data to include multi-digit versions.

Comment: Updated to also sort the textual items ("No version number", "Text", "").

Comment: This is a weird sort, with numeric versions descending, version suffixes ascending, followed by text ascending, but with empties at the end, but I think this does what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks great! Only thing is. How do I get it to work with my table? :)

Comment: You'd modify the `sort` function to do the comparisons on the `textContent` of the cell you care about instead of operating on `a` and `b` directly. Then you'd run a `querySelector` to get the rows, turn the rows into an array, and call `const sortedRows = rows.sort(sort)`, which will—you guessed it—return the sorted rows. Then put the sorted rows back into the table.

Comment: I've updated the snippet to demonstrate basic table row sorting.

Comment: Thanks! I had to run it through Babel and change to the second child of the tr, but it works the way I want now!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your sorting routing just takes the second char into account so it doesn't really make a difference between 2a and 2b.

I'd recommend constructing a decimal number out of the second char (1, 2 and 3) , the ASCII code of the next character (a, b, .) and ultimately compare these values instead.

```js
function sortTable(table, order, selector, target) {
  selector = selector || 'th:first-child, td:first-child';
  var asc = order === 'asc';
  target = target || '';

  var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table;
  var nodes = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var sortedNodes = Array.prototype.slice.apply(nodes);
  sortedNodes.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.querySelector(selector).textContent;
    var textB = b.querySelector(selector).textContent;
    var temp;
    var temp2;
    if (target == 'versions') {
      if (textA.match(/^v\d.*/i)) {
        temp2 = textA.charCodeAt(2);
        if (temp2 == 46) {
          temp2 = 0;
        } else {
          temp2 = (100 - textA.charCodeAt(2)) / 100
        }
        temp = (parseInt(textA.substr(1)) + temp2);
        textA = temp;
      }
      if (textB.match(/^v\d.*/i)) {
        temp2 = textB.charCodeAt(2);
        if (temp2 == 46) {
          temp2 = 0;
        } else {
          temp2 = (100 - textB.charCodeAt(2)) / 100
        }
        temp = (parseInt(textB.substr(1)) + temp2);
        textB = temp;
      }

    }
    result = textA - textB;
    if (isNaN(result)) {
      return (asc) ? textA.toString().localeCompare(textB) : textB.toString().localeCompare(textA);
    } else {
      return (asc) ? -result : result;
    }
  });
  tbody.textContent = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedNodes.length; i++) {
    tbody.appendChild(sortedNodes[i]);
  }
}
sortTable(document.getElementById('versions'), 'asc', '', 'versions');
```

```html
<table id="versions">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>v2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>v3.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>v2a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>v2.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No version number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>v1.0 Work in Progress</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only change would be to get "No version number", "Text" and "" at the end in that order. Also, does this work with v20.1a and v20.1b or is it locked to only one digit? Thanks!

Comment: It's sorting the elements at the end in this order. Unfortunately it's locked to one digit.